# Generate String based on multiple values just inserted

Tags: php, mysql

This one might be a bit complicated. I searched for similar questions and found nothing that seemed relevant.

Let me start by establishing my database structure.

I have several tables, but the relevant ones are as follows:
[image: Master Table]

[image: Card Table]

[image: Deck Table]

Right now I have the decklist stored as a string of `cardid` delimited by a comma. I realize this is inefficient and when I get around to improving my code I will make a new table `tcg_card_in_deck` that has `relationid`, `cardid`, `deckid`. For now my code assumes a `decklist` string.

I'm building a function to allow purchases of a deck. In order to give them the actual cards, I have the following query (generated with the PHP it will actually be about 50 entries):

```
$db->query_write("INSERT INTO 
`tcg_card` 
    (masterid, userid, foil)
VALUES 
    ('159', '15', '0'),
    ('209', '15', '0'),
    ('209', '15', '0'),
    ('318', '15', '0')");
```

This part is easy. My issue now is making sure the cards that have just been added can have their ids grabbed and put together in an array (to enter in as a string currently, and as entries into the separate table once the code is updated). If it was one entry I could use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. If I did 50 separate insert queries I could grab the id on each iteration and add them into the array. But because it's all done with one query, I don't know how to effectively find the correct cards to put in the decklist. I suppose I could add a dateline field to the cards table to specify date acquired, but that seems sloppy and it may produce flawed results if a user gets cards from a trade or a booster pack in a similar timeframe.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading comments on this question I thought of a very simple and easy solution:
[Get all inserted IDs when inserting multiple rows using a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540997/get-all-inserted-ids-when-inserting-multiple-rows-using-a-single-query)

I already track booster pack purchases with a table `tcg_history`. This table can also track other types of purchases, such as a starter deck.

I simply need to add a field on the `tcg_card` table that references a `tcg_history`.`recordid`, then I will be able to select all cards that are from that purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Change `tcg_card` by removing `cardid`, and make `masterid` and `userid` a compound key. Then, add a row called `quantity`. Since you cannot distinguish between two copies of a card in any meaningful way (except for being foils, which you could handle with this schema), there is no need for every card to get its own ID.

Presumably you aren't entering new `tcg_master` rows dynamically, so you don't have to worry about pulling their IDs back out.

Comment: This is a bit too sloppy. I want to make sure I track each individual card, because there are failsafes to delete decks if a card in the deck is traded off.

Comment: Is the implication that a card can only belong to one deck at a time, then? This actually seems like it'd be bad for users (i.e., "why can't I have this card in two decks at once if I can only play with one deck at a time?").

Comment: As a further update: if this is the case, then you may as well create your `tcg_card_in_deck` table now, because whatever solution you come up with is going to be obsolete once that table exists. Don't waste time engineering a solution that has an expiration date, just do it right from the beginning.

Comment: I don't know, thinking about it I understand where you're coming from but I'm not sure if it's the best approach. I do allow users to have cards in more than 1 deck. All of the code across multiple pages and functions assumes each card has an ID, so I need to know that this method is superior before I go through and change everything.

Comment: It sounds like your refactoring may be exacerbated by a rigid architecture. I'd recommend looking at the [Data Access Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) pattern to keep your code changes to a minimum in the face of database changes.

Comment: Take for example the trading/deckbuilding. I have put together a gallery view that allows users to view their cards in a visual gallery. They just click on the cards they want to use. Right now each card is within a label to a hidden checkbox, and the checkbox has a value of the cardid. I prevent duplicates of the same cardid, so I would have to redo my code to instead query the cardlist, check quantity, and ensure user isn't trying to use more copies than they own.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, just that it is a lot of work to change everything. I don't see how a Data Access Object would prevent this.