# Get last inserted IDS in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get ALL inserted ID`s after multiple insert  in MySQL by ONE query?
Example(abstract):

```
$ids = array();
$parts = array();
$query = 'INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`FIELDS`)  VALUES'; 

$items = array(values);
foreach($items as $item){
   $parts[] = '('.$item['key1'].','.$item['key2']...','.$item['keyN'].')';
}

$query .= implode(',',$parts);
mysqli_query($link,$query);
$ids = ... // getting  ALL inserted IDs
var_dump($ids);
```

It can do so here (one of solutions). Example(abstract):

```
$ids = array();

$items = array(values);
foreach($items as $item){
   $query ='INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`FIELDS`)  VALUES('.$item['key1'].','.$item['key2']...','.$item['keyN'].')';
   mysqli_query($link,$query);
   $ids[] = mysqli_insert_id($link);
}
var_dump($ids);
```

But, I would like to : one query INSERT all items - one query get ALL inserted ids.

**UPDATE**

My solution ( based on question [generate an integer sequence in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql) ).Return sequence of last inserted ID`s by single query.

```
$query_inserted_ids = "SELECT @row := @row +1 AS row_id
                       FROM TABLENAME , (SELECT @row := LAST_INSERT_ID()-1 )r
                       WHERE @row <(
                       SELECT id
                       FROM  TABLENAME 
                       ORDER BY id DESC
                       LIMIT 1 )";
```

Thanks for attention!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540997/get-all-inserted-ids-when-inserting-multiple-rows-using-a-single-query

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Will return the FIRST ID returned from a multi-line insert.
If you combine it with

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT()
```

you can start with the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and increment by the number of records specified in [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).